# get total item price in order Magento 2

Tags: magento2, orders, quoteitem, grand-total, cart-items

I want to get total item price from order item, including it's tax and any other additional price. Currently i got total price of an order item in like this:

```
$qty = $_item->getQtyOrdered();
$totalPrice = $_item->getPrice() * $qty;
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can use the below function to fetch Total Row Price including tax.

```
$_item->getRowTotalInclTax()
```

Also you can check `sales_order_item` table columns for other possible values available to fetch on `Order Item` object.